# How block/allow acceess to nginx based on a file without modfification it?

Tags: nginx

I want to limit access to nginx. Deny all and allow some IPs and networks based on a file.
The file has the following structure:

```
# comment
192.168.0.1
192.168.10.1/24 # another comment
... etc
```

The file should not be modified unless it is impossible. It is downloaded from the internet.

The ngx_http_access_module does not have an option to read input from file. I can use include directive but I have to modify the file to match to nginx syntax.

Is it possible for nginx to read such a file without modifying it? How?
Otherwise, I will have to use the geo module:

> In case of a lot of rules, the use of the ngx_http_geo_module module variables is preferable.

Comment: Which file you mean 'impossible' in the context?  Im also using nginx.. I didn't get you

Comment: It means: I don't want to modify a downloaded file unless it's necessary. I want to use it as it is. Each line has one entry: IP or network with or without comment.

Comment: Your need is to allow few IP to access your web server and you want to deny the access for others..

Comment: You can make it with the config files of nginx itself

Comment: From my knowledge nginx config files has to have proper syntax, for example:

`
allow 192.168.0.1;
allow 192.168.10.1/24;
`

Comment: I will share you the configuration to allow access for one IP and deny rest of the world

Comment: From core module:
> Includes another _file_, or files matching the specified _mask_, into configuration. Included files should consist of syntactically correct directives and blocks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101510/discussion-between-manikandan-ram-and-piecia).

Answer (score 0):

You can automatically transform the file into a format understood by nginx. E.g. you can run:

```
awk '/^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/{print"allow "$1";"}' your_file >new_file
```

and use the converted file with nginx.

**Edit**: if the goal is to force **nginx** to parse your file directly, you can modify **nginx** itself: since the [http access module](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/16168dcb01ed5dbf6365be0d9ea0da68bf479194/src/http/modules/ngx_http_access_module.c) applies the rules in a linear way, you'd better modify the [geo ip module](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/16168dcb01ed5dbf6365be0d9ea0da68bf479194/src/http/modules/ngx_http_access_module.c) and use the **nginx**'s `ngx_radix_tree_t` to store and search your addresses.

Comment: It is not possible without modification a file. Thanks a lot for all.

Comment: If an automatic transformation of your file into one which is **nginx** compatible is not what your are looking for, you can always modify **nginx** itself to read your file. The word _“impossible”_ is a little exaggerated in this context.

Comment: Yes, you are right.